# Using object property in select

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the following select:

```
<select ng-model="current_event"
        ng-options="event.event_id for event in current_level.events.event"
        ng-change="currentEventChanged()">
</select>
```

`current_level.events.event` is an array of objects which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "event_id": 0,
        "event_type": {
            "collision": {
                "object_id1": 0,
                "object_id2": 1,
                "allow_overlap": "no"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "event_id": 1,
        "event_type": {
            "player_input": {
                "object_id": 0,
                "level_id": 0,
                "allow_overlap": "no"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The select works perfectly, but the text for each option is just the `event_id`, e.g. "0" or "1". I want the text for an item to actually be the `event_type` (with underscores converted to spaces), e.g. "collision" or "player input". Is this possible in AngularJS?

Comment: Can you change the JSON to make player_input and collision values instead of property names? You can also move formatting to server side.

Comment: Something like {
        "event_id": 0,
        "display" : "Collision",
        "event_type": {
            "collision": {
                "object_id1": 0,
                "object_id2": 1,
                "allow_overlap": "no"
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `event.event_id`, so there is nothing wrong in the behaviour of AngularJS. You should simply put the right `label` in the `ng-options` of `<select>` (see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)).

However, you need to call a function before in order to obtain the correct label, since what you want is pretty complex.

```js
$scope.getLabel = function (eventType)
{
    var firstKey = null;
    angular.forEach(eventType, function (value, key)
    {
        if (firstKey === null)
        {
            firstKey = key;
        }
    });

    return firstKey.replace('_', ' ', 'g');
};
```

```xml
<select
    ng-model="current_event"
    ng-options="event.event_id as getLabel(event.event_type) for event in current_level.events.event"
    ng-change="currentEventChanged()"
>
</select>
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/VtukF/)</kbd>